# jquery play sound on body replacement

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, audio

I have a simple site which gets refreshed once every 30 seconds via a jquery full body refresh.

Now once a page refresh occurs I want a short sound to play and I tried to do this with various methods.

the methods work on my pc (IE, chrome and firefox) but the target is a samsung smart tv.

this is my site refresh with the sound added:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update_site() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // Replace body with loaded site. You can do more checks here to check
            // if the fetched content is all there.
            var body_html = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
                    .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");
            $('body').html(body_html);
            $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'blue');
            $("#goldengun").get(0).play();
        }, 
        error: function(data) {
            $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
}

// Run every 20 secs.
window.setInterval(function() {
  update_site();
}, 20000);
</script>

<style>

.last_connect {
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 4%;
    width: 2%
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="last_connect">
</div>

<audio id='goldengun'>
  <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<button type="button" onclick="update_site();">update site!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

like I said this works in my browsers but not on the smart tv, the window refreshes successfully but the sound does not get played. However if I make a single function which ONLY plays the audio and call that on my setinterval it works. If call that function from my update_site() function it doesn`t work. it seems to me this some kind of syncing issue where the browser has not yet loaded everything and it already request to play the sound.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you using a .wav file instead of mp3? Your TV may not support it.
Also, IOS and Android have security on audio files, not allowing them to be played by automatic methods (like .play() in a timer). It will however play if initiated by user interaction, like pressing a button. It's possible the TV has the same kind of security.

Comment: it does play if I only a play on the timer, no refresh. but once I combine a refresh and a play it doesn`t work

Answer (score 2):

use Buzz ( http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/ ). I love it. It uses html5 audio and can play ogg, mp3, and wav as long as the browser supports in in js without creating an audio element.

Example:

```
function playSound(){
    var mySound = new buzz.sound( "/sounds/sound", {
        formats: [ "ogg", "mp3", "aac" ]
    });
    mySound.play();
}
```

or even simpler:

```
var sound = new buzz.sound('assets/audio/sound.mp3');
```

and then where you call the function, call `sound.play();`

Unless and maybe even if you are dynamically creating sound files, you should know the names. So load the body with jQuery's `.load()` like so:

`$('body').load('newPage.html body');`

now you can know when the load is complete instead of a refresh which one can't listen for.

So do:

```
var sound = new buzz.sound("/sounds/sound.mp3");
$('body').load('newPage.html body', function(){
    sound.play();
});
```

So what this does is it defines the sound, then loads newPage.html's body into the current page's body and when that is done, it plays the sound.

I recommend having the new sound associated with the new page's name or store in a variable.

Suppose I need to load new page and play sound ' abc.mp3 ' on click of an element, I can do:

```
var sound = new buzz.sound('/sounds/sound.mp3');
$('.element').click(function(){
    var pageToLoad = 'abc';
    $('body').load(pageToLoad+'.html body', function(){
        sound = new buzz.sound('sounds/'+pageToLoad+'.mp3');
        sound.play();
    });
});
```

What this does it defines the sound. Then on an event, in this case on click of anything with the class="element", it loads the body of page abc.html and then plays abc.mp3 once that loading is finished.

Comment: the problem is the sound gets reloaded every page refresh and can be different than the one before.

Comment: @RG337 don't use page refresh. Use jQuery's .load to load the content and then on success of that load, redefine the sound. Do you have a list of possible file names?

Comment: Sadly the list isn`t complete as the first page loads as the sounds can dynamically change while the page is refreshing... also your refresh example can`t check if the page refresh is succesfull. I only want the page refresh if the page can be refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Unable to test, but perhaps something like this would work?

The following script in the test.html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var aud = $('<audio>').attr('id', 'goldengun');
    var src = $('<source>').attr('src', 'test.mp3').attr('type', 'audio/mpeg');
    aud.append(src);
</script>
```

The following function in caller page:

```
function update_site() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // Replace body with loaded site. You can do more checks here to check
            // if the fetched content is all there.
            var body_html = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
                    .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");

            $('body').html(body_html);
            $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'blue');

            $('body').append(aud);  
            aud.get(0).play();

        }, 
        error: function(data) {
            $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
}

window.setInterval(function() {
      update_site();
    }, 1000);
```

Or just try:

```
function update_site() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // Replace body with loaded site. You can do more checks here to check
            // if the fetched content is all there.
            var body_html = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
                    .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");

            $('body').html(body_html);
            $('#goldengun', body_html).get(0).play();
            $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'blue');

        }, 
        error: function(data) {
            $('.last_connect').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
}
```

It's quite likely that the browser itself under Android is disallowing .play() calls in a timed loop.